# Tor alternatives (change IP address often)

Tags: proxy, tor, ip

Are there any services that like Tor let you have many IP addresses and change them quite often?
PS. The problem with Tor is that they list publicly their exit nodes, so its very simple to detect that user is behind Tor network and act accordingly.

Comment: You could, of course, use the Tor protocol and band up with a bunch of like-minded people and make your own parallel Tor service, akin to Bitcoin's TestNet. Or you could find yourself a distributed botnet. But that would be illegal.

Comment: Yes, but I think making my own network is a little bit too much.

Comment: If you're relying on some public network rather than forming your own, you end up with a network that will soon have the same problem you apply to Tor -- the exit nodes will be listed. The problem is not that Tor publicly lists them, the problem is that even without that list, if the network is publicly usable it's trivial to develop the list on your own with a simple honeypot.

Comment: 1- Keep crawl anonymous proxy servers. 2- Keep testing them for availability. 3- Keep rotating them with simple FoxyProxy-like wizardry.

Comment: May be you are looking for simple proxy switching...this link may help http://techwalablog.blogspot.in/2013/06/online-anonymity.html?m=1